# quotchap: Changing formatting and number size

Tags: sectioning, formatting, fontsize, quotchap

I am using the `quotchap` package to format chapter headings in a document. I know how to change the default font size for the chapter headings, but I don't know how to make it bold.
I would like also to know if I can change the size of the Chapter Number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine the `\sectfont` and `\chapnumfont` macros.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{quotchap}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{%
  \usefont{T1}{\@defaultcnfont}{b}{n}\fontsize{120}{150}\selectfont% Default: 100/130
  \color{chaptergrey}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are there two values for `\fontsize`?